Terraform - s3 static website wont deploy, telling me I dont have permissions when I do
I am trying to deploy a frontend to an S3 bucket using Terraform, and I am receiving 403 AccessDenied errors when Terraform attempts to set the S3 bucket ACL and policy. Below are the error messages:

PutBucketAcl: AccessDenied: User is not authorized to perform s3:PutBucketAcl because public access control lists (ACLs) are blocked by the BlockPublicAcls setting.
PutBucketPolicy: AccessDenied: User is not authorized to perform s3:PutBucketPolicy because public policies are blocked by the BlockPublicPolicy setting.

I have already tried the following:

Setting the aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block resource to disable the block public ACLs and policies.
Ensuring the IAM user has s3:PutBucketAcl and s3:PutBucketPolicy permissions.
Verified that no organizational-level policies are blocking these actions.

Despite these steps, the error persists. How can I resolve this issue?
Terraform version:  v1.5.7
Code:
resource "random_pet" "frontend_name" {}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "frontend_bucket" {
  bucket = "frontend-bucket-${random_pet.frontend_name.id}"
  force_destroy = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "frontend_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id
  acl    = "public-read"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "frontend_website" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

  index_document {
    suffix = "index.html"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "frontend_public_access_block" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

  block_public_acls       = false
  block_public_policy     = false
  ignore_public_acls      = false
  restrict_public_buckets = false
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_cors_configuration" "frontend_cors" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

  cors_rule {
    allowed_methods = ["GET"]
    allowed_origins = ["*"]
    allowed_headers = ["*"]
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "s3_sync" {
  depends_on = [null_resource.build_frontend]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      AWS_PROFILE=${var.aws_profile} aws s3 sync ../frontend/dist/ s3://${aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id}/
    EOT
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "frontend_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}


Error:
╷
│ Error: creating S3 Bucket (frontend-bucket-giving-unicorn) ACL: operation error S3: PutBucketAcl, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 8FPDNEDW1WNKTKS2, HostID: V4Bv6r2nOUjVdpK9hbKfo2CLEK9fBVou3Mnw1pp29vM6pabH47V6CSgNiZ2XW5tCLt3o2ljpDtA=, api error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::<removed>:user/Admin is not authorized to perform: s3:PutBucketAcl on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::frontend-bucket-giving-unicorn" because public access control lists (ACLs) are blocked by the BlockPublicAcls block public access setting.
│ 
│   with module.frontend.aws_s3_bucket_acl.frontend_acl,
│   on frontend/s3.tf line 8, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "frontend_acl":
│    8: resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "frontend_acl" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: putting S3 Bucket (frontend-bucket-giving-unicorn) Policy: operation error S3: PutBucketPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 8FP73W1TMVZZKQY1, HostID: 7pEKSxxeNBrKX9gif/qnpkl5yWJXmcbureAH5qGIJH6EJNZTaTfBaJNNiUP5non2ens+Z5bsyI8=, api error AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:iam::<removed>:user/Admin is not authorized to perform: s3:PutBucketPolicy on resource: "arn:aws:s3:::frontend-bucket-giving-unicorn" because public policies are blocked by the BlockPublicPolicy block public access setting.
│ 
│   with module.frontend.aws_s3_bucket_policy.frontend_bucket_policy,
│   on frontend/s3.tf line 50, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "frontend_bucket_policy":
│   50: resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "frontend_bucket_policy" {
│ 
╵


IAM User - Admin policies (should be able to do everything):
IAM User Permissions Screenshot

For the first error, try
resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "frontend_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id
  acl    = "public-read"

depends_on = [
  aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.frontend_public_access_block,
]
}

For the second one
resource "aws_s3_bucket_policy" "frontend_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id

  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.frontend_bucket.id}/*"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY

depends_on = [
  aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block.frontend_public_access_block,
]
}


I dont understand, I need to put in these policies to allow for a public connection to my S3 bucket? Or are you saying it already has public access and I don't need to do this?

I just modified the response. you need to apply aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block right after the creation of bucket and after aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls that you don't use.

Thank you! But I also had to remove the aws_s3_bucket_acl altogether:
In 2020, AWS introduced stronger restrictions on public access to S3 resources by default, with the introduction of block public access settings.
AWS added a feature to block all public access at both the account and bucket levels. These settings override any attempts to make a bucket public using ACLs like public-read.
To now use Bucket Policies Instead: AWS now recommends using bucket policies to grant public access rather than relying on ACLs like public-read.
